# jquery tablesorter not working for table obtained via ajax but working for static table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

If I create a table in an HTML document and insert

```
$('#class_roster').tablesorter();
```

in the $(document).ready function, the table can be sorted and tablesorter works as expected. However, if the page loads, the user clicks a button in a form to request a specific table and the table is sent back via AJAX, the table displays, the tablesorter css is applied, but the sort icons do not appear and the table isn't sortable. No errors appear. This is browser independent (e.g., Chrome 29 and Firefox 23).

The AJAX call is within a validate function. Here are snippets:

```
/* Validate the info entered */
$('#loadTable').validate({
    rules: {
        snip
    },
    messages: {
        snip
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/snip", 
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                snip
            },
            success: function(data){
                var theResult = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#Student_Info').html(theResult.Student_Info); /* displays table in div 'Student_Info' */
                $('#class_roster').tablesorter();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The table looks like this in both cases:

```
<table id="class_roster" class="tablesorter" >
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th> ... </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Info 1</td><td>Info 2</td> ... </tr>
        <tr><td>Info 1</td><td>Info 2</td> ... </tr>
        <tr><td>Info 1</td><td>Info 2</td> ... </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not sure why the code works when the table is present when the document is loaded vs. not works when the table is dynamically generated. (To be clear, I have two otherwise identical pages.)

There are a number of questions looking at appending rows to a table via AJAX, and there's even an example of that on the tablesorter site, but I can't find any relating to an entirely new table.

**UPDATE**

It turns out to have been a browser caching problem. Both browsers had been exposed to development code, but for some reason weren't updating the javascript file. I have Firefox set to delete everything when quitting, and when I restarted it (for a different reason), my code as posted worked.
Sorry about that: It didn't occur to me to check for browser caching problems.

Comment: Is this a new table being inserted into the page already containing a `class_roster` table? That is, do you now have two tables with the same id?

Comment: If you end up having 2 tables with same id, table sorter will only work on any one of the table.

Comment: The two tables are in different pages. In page 1, the static table is the only table. In page 2, the dynamic table is the only table. I did this to check other aspects of the code (e.g., correct libraries loaded, typos in name, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Put this in DOM ready event:

```
$("#class_roster").tablesorter();
```

Try this in ajax success call:

```
$("#class_roster").trigger("update");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried that, and no change in behavior: The dynamic table still has no sorting icons and can't be sorted. I don't know if this is relevant, but the whole validate function is in the $(document).ready function.

Comment: Strange! This is working in my case. Put your code in fiddle.